# Resources to learn the Open Sicilian

Tags: learning, sicilian-defense, recommendations

As per the title, I'm looking for resources to learn the Open Sicilian. In particular, I would like to understand general themes and pawn structures instead of memorizing precise moves. For the record, I'm aware of Rios' book on pawn structures.

Comment: A word of caution: studying specific concrete lines is an essential part of learning the open sicilian, and it should not be completely neglected. Considering general themes and typical pawn structures is definitely not a bad thing, but it should not be the only thing you study.

Comment: Interesting, coming from a slower-paced repertoire I didn't consider that. May I ask you, as a ~1500-1600 FIDE, how much would you suggest I should memorize concrete variations, in both depth of a line and number of lines? I'm asking for rough indications, of course.

Comment: At that level I don't think you need to go too deep, as opponents in that range are bound to deviate from theory before move 15. As a rule of thumb, make sure to know the lines to a point where the resulting positions feel comfortable for you to handle on your own without fear. As for how many lines, focus on the main lines first; how many these are depends on the specific tabya. If you notice an opponent deviating from these, look it up after the game to see whether they blundered or if its a viable alternative that needs studying.

Comment: For example, after 1.e4, c5 2.Nf3 you have the starting tabya, and you begin by considering the main alternatives 2...d6, 2...Nc6, 2...e6, 2...g6. Due to their somewhat different characteristics, each of these need to be studied on their own, and broken down into sub-tabyas such as 2...d6 breaking down into sub-tabyas for the Najdorf and the Dragon subvariations (unless you decide to go with the Chekhover against 2...d6). In order not to get overwhelmed, begin with the branch with variations that you face most often, and take it one step at a time from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sure, I'll go as you mentioned. Do you think the four variations you mentioned share any tactical patterns e.g. the control of d5? I'm just trying to find some common ground between the variations to facilitate my work, although as you underlined concrete moves are essential to know.

Comment: Of course, there are common themes all across different lines of the sicilian. What you need to appreciate though, is that there are subtle difference between different lines that share a lot of commonalities (take the Sveshnikov vs. the Kalashnikov for instance, or the accelerated dragon vs. the classical dragon). There are often quite concrete reasons why the variations are a bit different although the variations look very similar to one another at a superficial level.

Comment: But yeah, control over d5 is a big theme across many lines in the sicilian, and different lines are (in some way) different alternative approaches for black to handle this.

Comment: You might consider the book Sicilian Warfare by Ilya Smirin. It is focused on typical themes in the Open Sicilian rather than particular lines or variations. Chapters include "The Killer Knight on f5," "The Exchange Sacrifice" and "Typical Attacks," to give you a sense of the content.

Comment: Thank you folks!